# Пoгoда html python ошибки

Tags: python, html, css

Решил повторить создание погоды но получилось что-то не так

````
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Пагода</title>

    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
    <input id="location" type="text" placeholder="Город\Страна" required="">

<body>
    <button id="now"> Узнать </button>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        async function display_weather() {
            Let place = document.getElementById("location").value
            Let res = await eel.get_weather(place)();
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = res:
        }
        
        jQuery('#show').on('click',function() {
            display_weather()
        }
    
    >
</body>

</html>```




PYTHON

```import eel
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM("СКРЫТО")
@eel.expose
def get_weather(place):
    pass

    place = input("Город\Страна :")
    
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
    w = observation.weather
        
    t = w.temperature("celsius") 
    t1 = t["temp"]
    t2 = t["feels_like"]
    return "в городе/стране, {place} температура {t1} ,ощущение {t2}"


eel.init("web")
eel.start("index.html", size = (200, 250))```

Могу еще CSS приложить
````

Answer (score 0):

```
import eel
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM("СКРЫТО")
@eel.expose
def get_weather(place):
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
    w = observation.weather
        
    t = w.temperature("celsius") 
    t1 = t["temp"]
    t2 = t["feels_like"]
    return f"в городе/стране, {place} температура {t1} ,ощущение {t2}"


eel.init("web")
eel.start("index.html", size = (200, 250))
```

Comment: Как мне сделать вывод по кнопке в приложении?

Comment: @user15091863, учить документацию, а не хауди хо

Comment: Можешь скинуть?

Comment: Где их брать???